# Can we have a "plea for attention" LQP comment?

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts, not-an-answer

These are the auto-comments that I can post for a self-answer:

[image]

I recently saw a non-answer by the question author that was something like this:

> plz, i can haz ancorz?plz

(Okay, it had a bit more fluency than lolcats. But still.)

In any other situation I'd use the "I'm having this problem, too" comment. But since that's not available, I can't see a clear option for what comment to go with. Can we have a new one that would be something like this?

> If you want more attention for your question, you can [add a bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) <once you have enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation)>. You can also edit the question to clarify and improve it.

Alternatively, what pre-existing comment, if any, should I use?

Comment: What's wrong with bespoke handmade artisan comments?

Comment: Or the cold uncaring "no comment needed"?

Comment: Does this particular situation really occur often enough to warrant adding another item to that list? I can't say I've run across a ton of OPs posting answers just for attention.

Comment: or a "recommend deletion"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That list is already pretty long as it is. On my laptop screen, it barely fits vertically and scroll areas inside scroll areas are a real pain.

I rarely use these default comments at all, often because they don't fit my needs. If I really want to comment on an answer, I write one myself. You should do this, too. There's no possible way for us to have a comment for every possible usage.

I also recommend considering adding the magical Script [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se). This allows you to write your favorite, oft used comments (they can be synced across systems) and save them for all eternity (or until your drive fails). You can save comments by post type (question or answer or either) and sort them however you like. It includes some default ones but you can always add more of your own.